# PHP Codeigniter Change number of data displayed in table

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I have a table that is displaying some data from a database. I want to be able to select from a dropdownlist if I want to show 5, 10 or 20 results. I already created a dropdownlist. What I was thinking was to create an onClick event the change the value of  $config["per_page"] = 20; but I don't know how to do that. My config file for pagination is a file called pagination.php

This is my view :

```
<div class="portlet box blue-madison">
   <div class="portlet-title">
      <div class="caption">
         <i class="fa fa-bank"></i>Notifications
      </div>
      <div class="tools">
         <a href="javascript:;" class="collapse"></a>
         <!--<a href="#portlet-config" data-toggle="modal" class="config"></a>-->
         <a href="javascript:;" class="reload"></a>
         <!--<a href="javascript:;" class="remove"></a>-->
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="portlet-body">
      <div class="table-responsive">
         <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="logs">
            <thead>
               <tr role="row" class="heading">
                  <th>
                     #
                  </th>
                  <th>
                     Date
                  </th>
                  <th>
                     Destinataire
                  </th>
                  <th>
                     Message
                  </th>
                  <th>
                     Expéditeur
                  </th>
               </tr>
               <tr role="row" class="filter">
                  <form class="filter" id="frm-flt-log_send" onsubmit="return false;">
                     <td> </td>
                     <td> </td>
                     <td> </td>
                     <td> </td>
                     <td>
                        <!--<div class="margin-bottom-5">
                           <button class="btn btn-sm green btn-outline filter-submit margin-bottom" onclick="loadCompanies('<?php //echo site_url('notifications/main/lst')?>')"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Filtrer</button>
                           </div>
                           <button class="btn btn-sm red btn-outline filter-cancel" onclick="this.form.reset();loadLog_send();"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Reset</button>-->
                     </td>
                  </form>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody  id="log_send-ajax-content">
               <?php $this->load->view('log_send/list_ajax.php');?>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="portlet-body">
      <img class ="ico" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/images/gris.png"> Etat inconnu
      <img class ="ico" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/images/bleu.png"> Notification envoyée
      <img class ="ico" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/images/vert.png"> Notification reçue
      <img class ="ico" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/images/rouge.png"> Erreur dans l'envoi
   </div>
   <div class="portlet-body">
      <img class ="ico" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/images/ok.png"> Quittance OUI
      <img class ="ico" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/images/nok.png"> Quittance NON
      <img class ="ico" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/images/unkown.png"> Non quittancé (raccroché)
   </div>
</div>
```

And the data passed into the table :

```
<?php
   foreach ($content as $value){
   switch($value->id_send_type){
    case "1": // SMS
        switch ($value->etat){
            case "Msg read complete":
                $etat = "<img id=\"".$value->ticket."\" class=\"ico\" src=\"".base_url()."/assets/images/send_type/sms_vert.png\">";
            break;
            case "Msg send complete":
                $etat = "<img id=\"".$value->ticket."\" class=\"ico\" src=\"".base_url()."/assets/images/send_type/sms_bleu.png\">";
            break;
            case "Msg Pending":
                $etat = "<img id=\"".$value->ticket."\" class=\"ico\" src=\"".base_url()."/assets/images/send_type/sms_orange.png\">";
            break;
            default:
                $etat = "<img id=\"".$value->ticket."\" class=\"ico\" src=\"".base_url()."/assets/images/send_type/sms_gris.png\">";
            break;
        }
        $quittance = "<img id=\"q".$value->ticket."\" class=\"ico\" src=\"".base_url()."/assets/images/vide.png\">";
    break;
    case "2": // Email
        $etat = "<img id=\"".$value->ticket."\" class=\"ico\" src=\"".base_url()."/assets/images/send_type/mail_bleu.png\">";
        $quittance = "<img id=\"q".$value->ticket."\" class=\"ico\" src=\"".base_url()."/assets/images/vide.png\">";
    break;
    case "3": //Appel vocaux
        switch ($value->etat) {
            case 'ring':
                $etat = "<img id=\"".$value->ticket."\" class=\"ico\" src=\"".base_url()."/assets/images/send_type/appel_ring.png\">";
            break;
            case 'hangup':
                $etat = "<img id=\"".$value->ticket."\" class=\"ico\" src=\"".base_url()."/assets/images/send_type/appel_vert.png\">";
            break;
            default:
                $etat = "<img id=\"".$value->ticket."\" class=\"ico\" src=\"".base_url()."/assets/images/send_type/appel_bleu.png\">";
            break;
        }
        switch ($value->quittance) {
            case '1':
                $quittance = "<img id=\"q".$value->ticket."\" class=\"ico\" src=\"".base_url()."/assets/images/ok.png\">";
            break;
            case '3':
                $quittance = "<img id=\"q".$value->ticket."\" class=\"ico\" src=\"".base_url()."/assets/images/nok.png\">";
            break;
            case '9':
                $quittance = "<img id=\"q".$value->ticket."\" class=\"ico\" src=\"".base_url()."/assets/images/unkown.png\">";
            break;
            default:
                $quittance = "<img id=\"q".$value->ticket."\" class=\"ico\" src=\"".base_url()."/assets/images/vide.png\">";
            break;
        }
    break;
    case "4": // Pager
        switch ($value->etat){
            case "Msg read complete":
                $etat = "<img id=\"".$value->ticket."\" class=\"ico\" src=\"".base_url()."/assets/images/send_type/pager_vert.png\">";
            break;
            case "Msg send complete":
                $etat = "<img id=\"".$value->ticket."\" class=\"ico\" src=\"".base_url()."/assets/images/send_type/pager_bleu.png\">";
            break;
            case "Msg Pending":
                $etat = "<img id=\"".$value->ticket."\" class=\"ico\" src=\"".base_url()."/assets/images/send_type/pager_orange.png\">";
            break;
            default:
                $etat = "<img id=\"".$value->ticket."\" class=\"ico\" src=\"".base_url()."/assets/images/send_type/pager_gris.png\">";
            break;
        }
        $quittance = "<img id=\"q".$value->ticket."\" class=\"ico\" src=\"".base_url()."/assets/images/vide.png\">";
    break;

    case "5": //Threema
        $etat = "<img id=\"".$value->ticket."\" class=\"ico\" src=\"".base_url()."/assets/images/send_type/threema_bleu.png\">";
        $quittance = "<img id=\"q".$value->ticket."\" class=\"ico\" src=\"".base_url()."/assets/images/vide.png\">";
    break;

    case "7": //Fax
        switch ($value->etat) {
            case '0':
                $etat = "<img id=\"".$value->ticket."\" class=\"ico\" src=\"".base_url()."/assets/images/send_type/fax_vert.png\">";
            break;
            default:
                $etat = "<img id=\"".$value->ticket."\" class=\"ico\" src=\"".base_url()."/assets/images/send_type/fax_bleu.png\">";
            break;
        }
        $quittance = "<img id=\"q".$value->ticket."\" class=\"ico\" src=\"".base_url()."/assets/images/vide.png\">";
    break;

   }


    echo "<tr><td>".$etat.$quittance."</td><td>".$value->date."</td><td>".$value->recname." ".$value->recfirstname."<br><font size=\"0.5em\"><i>".$value->recipient."</i></font></td><td>".$value->message."</td><td>".$value->expname." ".$value->expfirstname."</td>";
    //echo '<td>' . (($value->active)?'<span class="badge  badge-success">on</span>':'<span class="badge badge-danger">off</span>')  . '</td>';
    //echo '<td><button class="btn btn-info" type="button" onClick="window.location.href = \'' . site_url('admin/company/edit/' . $value->id_company) . '\';">Modification</button></td>';

    echo '</tr>';   
   }

   ?>
<tr>
   <td colspan="8">
      <div class="dropdown">
         <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Résultats par page
         <span class="caret"></span></button>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">10</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">20</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="pagination"><?php echo $pag_links; echo $pag_total ;?></div>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question "how to catch the click event":

```
<select onchange='doSomething(this)'>
    <option value='5'>5</option>
    <option value='10'>10</option>
    <option value='15'>15</option>
</select>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function doSomething(elem) {
        alert('value = ' + elem.value);
    }
</script>
```

Now, if you need to display a different number of rows depending on the number chosen, you will need to play a little bit more with javascript. If you use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), your life will be easier.

Anyway, it has no point reinventing the wheel. Take a look at [datatables](https://www.datatables.net/), as they do exactly what you are asking for.

Best regards